# Passing $(this) to a callback in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, parameters, callback, this

I have two effects that I want to run one after another, but I can't work out how to pass `$(this)` to the callback from the first effect.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
if($(this).hasClass('flag')) {
    $('someElement').slideUp();
    $(this).slideDown();
}
```

But what I want is for the slideDown to run after the slideUp is complete, ie.

```
if($(this).hasClass('flag')) {
    $('someElement').slideUp(function() {
        $(this).slideDown();
    });
}
```

Except `$(this)` by that stage now refers to `someElement` instead and so doesn't work as planned.

How do I refer to my original `element.flag`. I tried using `$this = $(this)` but I think I must have the syntax wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save the reference.

```
if($(this).hasClass('flag')) {
    var el = this;
    $('someElement').slideUp(function() {
        $(el).slideDown();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

cache it like this... *just don't forget the*`var`.

```
var $this = $(this);
if($this.hasClass('flag')) {
    $('someElement').slideUp(function() {
        $this.slideDown();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
var self = $(this);
if(self.hasClass('flag')) {
    $('someElement').slideUp(function() {
        self.slideDown();
    });
}
```